Does this require asbestos abatement?
My contractor who was installing an attic ladder cut an asbestos insulated duct with friable insulation. It is now disturbed, an asbestos abatement companies are telling me the entire attic needs abated now. Is this overkill? I have small children and live in California.

California  usually has tougher regulations than some other places, so a company would need to go by the local regulations.  Can try other companies and see what they say.  Asbestos is usually safe if not disturbed and usually needs long term exposure.  Not going into the attic might be safe enough.
